# Exporting MDX query result to CSV file using ADOM library

Tags: ssas, iccube

In my code, I am using `ADOM library` to export MDX query result to CSV/xlsx file. It exports the data successfully in CSV/xlsx file format. But there is an additional tag `All-M` or `All-L` appended with Row and Column while there is no tag in SSAS (export the data from same ADOM to CSV).

I tried to remove All Level check box, remove (All) Level name and (All) Member name.

Export from icCube containing additionals tags `All-L` and `All-M`:

```
[Stress Scenarios].[Stress Scenario].[All-L].[MEMBER_CAPTION]
[Snapshots].[Reference Date].[All-M].&[2018-01-02].[Measures].[Market Value Sensitivity]
```

Export from SSAS :

```
[Stress Scenarios].[Stress Scenario].[MEMBER_CAPTION]
[Snapshots].[Reference Date].&[2018-01-02T00:00:00].[Measures].[Market Value]
```

**I need an export output from icCube as below**

Export from icCube:

```
[Stress Scenarios].[Stress Scenario].[MEMBER_CAPTION]
[Snapshots].[Reference Date].&[2018-01-02T00:00:00].[Measures].[Market Value]
```

Comment: Can you explain "export uing ADOM" ?

Comment: Apology Marc  it is "ADOMD"

Comment: Yes what do you mean by "export" ? Are you sending an MDX query using ADOMD and then generate by yourself a CSV file from the result ?  What is "[Stress Scenarios].[Stress Scenario].[All-L].[MEMBER_CAPTION]" ? where did you get it (which part of the result) ?